# Cannot connect ElephantSQL database to django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to connect elephant sql service to django. I configured db  settings in settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test_db1',
        'USER': 'xxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'arjuna.db.elephantsql.com',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

But It gives an error when I make migrations.

```
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "heffalump.db.elephantsql.com" (50.18.63.64), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "123.231.123.61", user "hlcreaar", database "test_db2", SSL on
connection to server at "heffalump.db.elephantsql.com" (50.18.63.64), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "123.231.123.61", user "hlcreaar", database "test_db2", SSL off
```

I tried adding port number 5432, but still it doesn't work. Can someone help me to fix this error?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32090651/fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-but-i-can-connect-trough-pgadmin

Comment: Please post text as text, not as images of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently run my connection as follows,

```
DATABASES = {

     'default': {

         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

         'NAME': 'test_db1',

         'USER': 'test_db1',

         'PASSWORD': '************************',

         'HOST': 'arjuna.db.elephantsql.com',

         'PORT': '5432',

     }
 }
```

Notice im using psycopg2. Name and User are the same.

The error is showing this host, "heffalump.db.elephantsql.com" Did you change the Database at some point? If you did, this might be the problem, and you probably need to do some work with the migrations.